# Optimizing a powershell batch rename script

Tags: powershell, performance

I wrote the script below to batch rename files with powershell. It is intended to remove dots (.) and every (-) that is followed by a number from the filenames. Example: text.10-1 becomes text101. However, I feel like there must be a way to do this in a line of code.
Also, I wanted it to also enter a subdirectory and do it, how do I write it?

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace(".",'')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-1",'1')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-0",'0')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-2",'2')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-3",'3')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-4",'4')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-5",'5')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-6",'6')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-7",'7')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-8",'8')+$_.Extension)" }
Get-ChildItem | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace("-9",'9')+$_.Extension)" }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?  Get-childitem in parens to avoid the "modifying the loop" problem.

```
echo hi | set-content -1.txt,-2.txt,-3.txt
(get-childitem) | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '-(\d)','$1' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\-1.txt Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\-2.txt Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\-3.txt Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\3.txt".
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried it out and it works quite well and fast as intended, but also renames files with ' - ' that is not followed by a number. How can I make it only remove the - if it's followed by a number, so it makes "-1" become "1", but "-a" remain "-a"? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I don't see that happening.  \d should only match numbers.  Like -a.txt doesn't get renamed.  What is an example filename that gets renamed that shouldn't?

Comment: Oh, I was reading the shell output incorrectly. It does work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single Get-ChildItem call:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Recurse) | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '[-.]' } |
Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '[-.](\d)', '$1'), $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Note: I have added switch `-WhatIf` for safety so you can first see what *would* happen in the console. When you are satisfied with that, remove the `-WhatIf` switch and run again to actually start renaming the files.

<sup>switch `-Recurse` lets Get-ChildItem also find files in subfolders</sup>

Comment: Hey there, I tried it out and it works quite well and fast as intended, but also renames files with ' - ' that is not followed by a number. How can I make it only remove the - if it's followed by a number, so it makes "-1" become "1", but "-a" remain "-a"? Thanks for your feedback.